# Is it possible to return color name with JQuery

Tags: html, tags

I have been searching for a while to get some suitable solution, but I have not found any.
I have webpage, where I have select tag with all colors - specified on this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp). Then in the middle of my code I try to set some color using jquery plugin like 
`$(<id>).val( $(<id2>).css("background-color") );` but jquery can't set color names because .css method returns color in rgb mode.

Does anyone knows if there exists easy solution for this problem, how to get actual color name from some element on page. There isn't any option to store color values in array or something like that, because webpage is very dynamic and such solutions can't be possible.

Regards,
Dahakka

Comment: can you show us your html?

Comment: this will help you

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117890/background-color-name-using-jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117890/background-color-name-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. When you give it a colour name, the browser computes it to an rgb value. Therefore, jQuery's `.css` method (which I believe calls on `getComputedStyle`) returns that rgb value.

The only way to get the original colour name back is by making a huge lookup table of [all the colour names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names), and matching against it - which of course relies on the browser returning the rgb format consistently (some browsers may have spaces where others don't).